# ImageResizer and security considerations

Tags: security, imageresizer

We are considering using ImageResizer in our commercial application and have some questions related to security.  The application will allow user upload of images for subsequent display on web pages.

We want to know how we can use ImageResizer to protect against attacks such as compression bomb, JAR content, payload, exif exposures,  and malformed image data.

I think I know how to address these in general, but I'd like to know what specific tools ImageResizer offers.

Answer (score 2):

Most ImageResizer data adapters offer an "untrustedData=true" configuration setting.

This setting in turn sets `&process=always` in the request querystring during the `ImageResizer.Configuration.Config.Current.Pipeline.PostRewrite` event.

If you wish, you can set it for all image requests. Keep in mind, this will cause requests for original images to be re-encoded at a potential quality loss and/or size increase.

When `process=always` is set, all images are re-encoded and stripped of exif data to prevent potentially malicious images from reaching the browser. This means the client will get a 500 error instead of a malformed image.

How an image is interpreted, however, is just as important. If you permit user uploads to preserve their original file name or just extension (instead of picking from a whitelist), you open yourself to easy attack vectors. In the same way, if an image is set to the browser with a javascript mime-type, the client may interpret it as javascript and get XSS'd. ImageResizer's pipeline works with whitelists to prevent this from happening.

Also, if you intend to re-encode all uploads, it may be easier to do it during the upload stage instead of on every request. However, this relies on the security of your data store and being sure that no 'as-is' uploads can succeed.

Comment: I do think that I want to re-encode once, on upload.   I'm not sure what you mean by "this relies on the security of your data store and being sure that no 'as-is' uploads can succeed"  I'm thinking that I would attempt a re-encode, relying on ImageResizer to let me know if there is a problem, e.g., invalid image content.  Ideally, if this occurs, I would substitute a stock image that indicates that an error occurred. Also, could you explain the whitelist feature?  What is getting whitelisted?

Comment: 1) I.e, if you accept public push to an S3 store, it won't matter if you re-encode during uploads funneled through your app server. 2) If you use the ImageResizer HttpModule, it will only serve images with image mime-types.